# Exchange Rule based on Sender From "Name" instead of address?

Tags: office365, exchange-server, email-spam, phishing

I'm trying to alleviate some phishing attacks that leverage a real From Name, but fake/variable From Address.

Essentially, someone will send an e-mail from John Smith, but the address is xnuinds@some-domain.com. I want to issue a rule associated with the name "John Smith" rather than the e-mail address xnuinds@some-domain.com.

We're having targeted phishing attacks where folks are creating free e-mail accounts and using legit names that it appears from. So it comes through as *John Smith xnuinds@some-domain.com* and essentially looks real unless you look at the underlying e-mail address.

The only options in our exchange admin center appears to be associated with e-mail addresses, rather than FROM names.

Has anyone tried to build any specific rules based on From Names before, rather than addresses?

[image: Exchange Admin Center Rule]

Answer (score 1):

Create an Anti spoof rule>>>

- Create a Mail Flow Rule:
- If the sender is outside the organization
- Condition > If the sender domain is internaldomain.com

Then

- Redirect email to hosted quarantine
- Generate an incident report

Exception:

- Add the IPs for: SMTP RELAY: printer , or scanner, website, applications

Answer (score 0):

I was able to implement a search for the “from” header containing employee names, of course it’s not dynamic so we have to manually add a name every time someone is added to active directory, but it’s a least working.